# Jointjs diagram to pdf showing mouseover link svg also

Tags: pdf, canvas, svg, jspdf, jointjs

I am exporting a diagram made using Jointjs library to pdf using jspdf and canvas:
Below is my javascript code::

```
        var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

        var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        var svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.fillStyle = '#FFFF';

        canvg(canvas, svgString);

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        // Generate PDF
        doc.setFontSize(10);
        doc.text(35, 25, "Google Cloud Craft");
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 50);
        doc.save('test.pdf');
```

the result i get after downloading and on canvas is:

[image]

What i want is those black arrow marks should not come as they are shown on mouseover events, it should be like below image for reference:

[image]

please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution sharing, so that if anyone faces this issue can get help.

this is the solution, who are familiar with jointjs will understand it.

```
link.attr({

            '.marker-arrowheads': {
                fill: 'none'
            },
            '.connection-wrap': {
                fill: 'none'
            },
            '.marker-vertices': {
                fill: 'none'
            },
            '.link-tools': {
                fill: 'none'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer.

Add the below code to hide the mouse-over elements before serialising it

```
   $(".marker-arrowhead").css("display", "none");
   $(".tool-remove").css("display", "none");
   $(".tool-options").css("display", "none");
   $(".marker-vertices").css("display", "none");
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for helping, it worked but i think correct will be adding this link attr, i am posting my answer

Comment: You need those arrows and mouseover element on runtime right ?. For drag and resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Here my proposition :)

```
const classes = ['.marker-vertices', '.link-tools'];
const svg = this.paper.svg.cloneNode(true);

// remove tools
classes.forEach(c => {
  const elements = svg.querySelectorAll(c);
  elements.forEach(el => { el.style.display = 'none'; });
});
```